# How I can Use TryParse with Console.Readile?

Tags: c#, tryparse

when I try to use TryParse I get error CS0029, pls see below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12;

            double notval = 0;
           
            Console.WriteLine("Please insert the rainfall in January:");
            m1 = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out notval) ;
```

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'double'" (CS0029).

Comment: `TryParse()` is returning a `bool` value, indicating if it did parse or parse not the string. The "result" is in the second variable given (here it's `notval`).

Comment: if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out notval)){ do your success logic}else{do your fail logic}

Comment: This is about the point that you don't ask questions, and just go to the documentation. Otherwise it will take you a million years to write something worthwhile. [double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

TryParse returns of it was successful at parsing or not, and puts the result (if successful) in the out parameter (on you case notval).. so use:

```
if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out notval))
{
    // Do what you want with notval
}
```